# Change state of buttons after URL change

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, button

I am trying to update the state of my menu buttons every time that my URL changes. The following code is on `mouseleave` of my buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnAdd, #btnEdit").mouseleave(function(event) {
        ActivateMenuButton();
    });     
});

function ActivateMenuButton() {
    var currentURL = window.location.pathname;
    //alert(currentURL);

    //deselect current selected button
    $("#btnAdd, #btnEdit").removeClass("buttonSelected");

    //select menu button according to URL
    if (currentURL.indexOf('Add') >= 0) {
        $("#btnAdd").addClass("buttonSelected");    
    }

    if (currentURL.indexOf('Ddit') >= 0) {
        $("#btnEdit").addClass("buttonSelected");   
    }
}
```

Is there a way through jQuery or javescript to detect when a page changes and fire the code above?

Comment: You can try to use the unload event: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be looking for jQuery.ready(), which fires when a page finishes loading. Your javascript code does not remember itself between page loads, and thus the mouseleave event is pointless, you want to just go ahead and fire ActivateMenuButton straight off.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { ActivateMenuButton(); });
```

Comment: Of course, what I was thinking of? Thank you. I was thinking outside the box, the problem is I was thinking outside the WRONG BOX :-)